# How to create new column that compares 2 other columns

Tags: r

I have dataset in R for samples (ID) for 2 years for one variable (Majorclade). I want to see how major clade have changed over the 2 years for each sample. I would like to create a column that compares it, like it is the same calls it 0, if different calls it 1. I imagine some kinda of mutate would do it, but I am not figuring it out. Ideas?

[image]

Table example:

Comment: Can you show the expected

Comment: Do you need `df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(new = +(n_distinct(Majorclade) > 1))`

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(new = +(n_distinct(Majorclade) > 1))  %>%   
    ungroup
```